# How to retrieve data from 2d array react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am retrieving data from one component in react that is being passed into another component as a 2d array.

`console.log(this.props.cheatsheet)` Results in `[object Object],[object Object]`

`console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.dashboards));`  shows me the arrays values below

```
[  
   {  
      "name":"Test",
      "description":"TEest",
      "filter":[  
         "201158",
         "200461",
         "201345"
      ],
      "KPIs":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"Asset Owner Dashboard",
      "description":"Description for Asset Owner Dashboard",
      "filter":[  
         "201732",
         "222323",
         323244
      ],
      "KPIs":[  
         {  
            "name":"Asset",
            "charts":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Details"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "name":"Incidents",
            "charts":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Count by AssignmentGroup"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"COE Open Tickets"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"NEW IM in Last 48hrs"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "name":"Problem Tickets",
            "charts":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Count by Status"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Open PMR"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Details"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

what is the best way for me to map the filter array from test and Asset Owner Dashboard

Comment: You can use lodashJs filter method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of nested maps to render you data. just like the below example

```js
class App extends React.Component {
   render(){
      var arr = [  
   {  
      "name":"Test",
      "description":"TEest",
      "filter":[  
         "201158",
         "200461",
         "201345"
      ],
      "KPIs":[  

      ]
   },
   {  
      "name":"Asset Owner Dashboard",
      "description":"Description for Asset Owner Dashboard",
      "filter":[  
         "201732",
         "222323",
         323244
      ],
      "KPIs":[  
         {  
            "name":"Asset",
            "charts":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Details"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "name":"Incidents",
            "charts":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Count by AssignmentGroup"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"COE Open Tickets"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"NEW IM in Last 48hrs"
               }
            ]
         },
         {  
            "name":"Problem Tickets",
            "charts":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Count by Status"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Open PMR"
               },
               {  
                  "name":"Details"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
      
      return (
        <tbody>
           {arr.map(function(item){
               return (
                  <tr>
                     {item.filter.map(function(val){
                       return <td>{val}</td>
                       
                      })}
                  </tr>
               )
           })} 
        </tbody>
      )
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.8/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Glad to have helped :)